# Trying toggle method to introduce new class on button click

Tags: html, jquery, css, toggle

I am trying to introduce new class for specific div element using `nth-child()` pseudo-class but it is not working!
Am I doing something wrong?

Note that `menu`, `container`, `newClass` are already defined in CSS section and I'm not showing them here.

Here is what I am trying:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function {
    $("div:nth-child(2)").toggleClass("newClass");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle CSS</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <lu>
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>option2</li>
      <li>option 3</li>
    </lu>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your browser console, you have an syntax error in your code

Comment: Can you highlight syntax error, as I'm working on my phone right now for a quick fix.

Comment: Look at the `click` handler. The `function` is missing `()`

Comment: In your click handler it should be `function() {` instead of `function {`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page and [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Dear clijsters thanks for your suggestion, I'm student of mathematics, and I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of mistakes in your code. Which `div` are you want to add a class `newClass`? I think your code should be like this

```js
$(function() {
    $("button").on('click', function() {
        $(".menu").toggleClass("newClass");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle CSS</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>option2</li>
      <li>option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to change class from **menu** to **new class** take a look at second div element

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I was not trying to change class of 2nd child of list element.

Comment: `$(function() {
  $("button").on('click', function() {
    $(".menu").toggleClass("newClass");
  });
});`
Try this one.

Comment: Perfect! Now you understand my point of view. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do not forget to mark as the right answer. Happy Coding.

Comment: Dear `Hasan` your answer is now marked as `right answer` , thank you for your help!

Comment: Please edit your answer with the one you suggested in comment(associated toggle with `menu` class instead of `list` ).

Answer (score 0):

### My mistake

I should not use

```
<script>
$("div:nth-child(2)").toggle Class("newClass");
</script>
```

this to introduce new class for `div` element, with the class `menu` , as it is not a second child of `div` . What given below is though working fine for me:

### Correction

```
<script>
$("div.menu").toggleClass("newClass");
</script>
```

> That is: to specify `div` element(whose class is going to be toggled) by tagging its class `menu` , to call `jQuery` for `div` with the class `menu` .
>   Also by mistake parentheses `()` were missing.